# Zend Framework 2 : unable to get servicelocator on a custom class

Tags: zend-framework2

I am unable to load service locatior on a custom class, see my error code below, any advice would be appriciated

```
namespace Application\Helper;



use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class EmailHelper implements  ServiceLocatorAwareInterface{

    protected $serviceLocator;


    public function testEmail($email){

        $config = $this->serviceLocator->get('Config');
        print_r($config); exit;


    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

}
```

> Call to a member function get() on null in
>   /var/www/html/engsvc_dev/module/Application/src/Application/Helper/EmailHelper.php
>   on line 23

Answer (score 3):

In order to inject the `ServiceManager` instance which is an implementation of `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface` you need to instantiate the class like this:

```
$emailHelper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('EmailHelper');
```

Also don't forget to register the class in Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'EmailHelper' => 'Application\Helper\EmailHelper'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use the servicelocator inside the EmailHelper class itself

Comment: The servicelocator is not being instantiated inside the EmailHelper class because you are most likely initialising the class using **new** instead of using dependency injection as in the answer above.

Comment: Yup, the service locator SHOULDN'T be used directly in your class (although you can), but through a Factory for your class... Only there you should ask him for your dependencies and pass them to your class' `__construct` method as paramters when you instantiate it ;)

Comment: Glad it worked, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.